# What is the use of Scroll Lock button in keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I can't understand the use of scroll lock.
I searched on Google, Wikipedia and used that particular technic but still I am confused.

Comment: Is it related to programming???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scroll lock is a remnant of the original IBM keyboard and its purpose was to alter the arrow key behavior when it was pressed.

Not many applications use scroll lock anymore, as we got the mouse for scrolling nowadays. Very few applications/pages/etc respect this old principle. Imagine it like num-lock key.

Here you can have all the details about it:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scroll_lock

Comment: I searched Wikipedia but i can't get particular use of it.

Comment: I upvoted you for your answer but my question is why is it on my keyboard and for what use of it in old time?

Comment: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/64623/why-do-modern-keyboards-have-scroll-lock
Thanks.
Check this out :)

Comment: This link is helpful Thanks :)